# Amazon Elastic Beansalk cron.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have deployed my app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. The app environment is common webserver.

Can cron.yaml file be used to create periodic jobs for common web server type environments as well? The documentation says its a way to create periodic jobs for worker type environments.

Answer (score 7):

I believe cron.yaml  is only for Worker environments.  The scheduled task feature is driven by SQSD, the utility that relays SQS messages via HTTP posts to your application.  Web tier environments do not have SQSD.

You can probably cook up an alternative using a scheduled Lambda function, though.

Comment: I am using a .ebextensions config file to create cron jobs. Not sure how reliable it it.

Comment: That will probably work just fine, but if you scale your environment up to more nodes, will you have duplicate events?

Comment: All my stuff is database(RDS) driven so it will work fine. But I will give lambda a try as well.

Comment: Where does the cron.yaml file go? ebextensions?

Answer (score 2):

[James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3587167/james) is right, adding more details for future google queries.

> [Periodic Tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks)
>
> Added February 17, 2015
>
> Run cron jobs that you configure in a cron.yaml file in your application source code.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks